# ¿Cual es la mejor solución para generar un reporte en pdf de muchos datos sin que tome mucho tiempo en realizarlo?

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, jspdf

Intento generar un reporte de una gran cantidad de datos que se generan a partir de varios factores, el hecho es que en el momento se está realizando por medio de [php](/questions/tagged/php) a través de la librería [tcPdf](https://tcpdf.org/) pero este proceso regularmente toma bastante tiempo en realizarse.

Con el ánimo de reducir los tiempos de espera desearía hacerlo desde el lado del cliente, investigando encontré una librería en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) de nombre [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) pero en realidad no sé si al realizar este proceso se logrará una diferencia significativa o en realidad sería lo mismo.

**¿Cual sería la mejor solución?**
**¿Existe una mejor manera de hacerlo?**

Comment: No sabría como mejorar la pregunta pues en realidad esta basada en opinion de gente mas experimentada que me ayude a encontrar una solución a mi problema, no esta basada en código si no en el tiempo de carga que me da el usar una librería y saber si al usar algo de [tag:javascript] va a mejorar el proceso :(

Comment: Se me ocurre que una forma de mejorar la pregunta sería incluir el código que estás utilizando con `tcPdf` (lo más reducido posible), mencionar cuánto tiempo tarda en promedio (para entender qué considerás que es bastante tiempo) y cambiar la pregunta de `mejor solución` a `cómo reducir el tiempo`

Comment: Esta bien, Gracias @Mariano

Answer (score 0):

Mejor crea un servicio web hecho en java, que te genere un reporte con la librería JasperReports, entonces tendrías un servicio dedicado a la generación de reportes, seria mas rapido y tu servidor php tendra menos carga de procesos.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que uses esta opción la tuve que usar en 2 ocasiones para aminorar el tiempo de ejecución al convertir HTML a PDF usando PHP.

https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Aquí más opciones que pueden servirte para trabajar con Wkhtmltopdf

http://phptrends.com/dig_in/Wkhtmltopdf